# Assign value to input fields in bootstrap tabs based on some condition

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am unable assign a value to input fields in bootstrap tabs based on a condition, it works fine in the first tab but not in the second tab.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#One" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
     <li class=""><a href="#Two" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li> 
</ul>

<div id="tabContent" class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="One">
          //Its works fine,and assigns the value to input field.
           <input type="text" value="{{($row->value== 1) ?'test':'')}}" />
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Two">
          //value is not assigned to input field though condition is true.
            <input type="text" value="{{($row->value== 1) ?'test':'')}}" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using twig? If I remember correctly, you only use {{}} for variables: {{myVar}}. For expressions, use {% %}.

{% $row->value == 1 ? 'test':'' %}

Comment: No i am not using twig,this is how laravel blade works.

Comment: Okay, so, one thing to try, is using a cleaner conditional
`@if ($row->value == 1)
    <input type="text" value="test" />
@else
    <input type="text" value="" />
@endif`

I'd also suggest assigning the values for the two inputs to separate variables, and see what happens:
`<input type="text" value="{{$row->input1}}" />
<input type="text" value="{{$row->input2}}" />`

Something funny is going on with the template rendering, so, those might help figure it out.

Also, dump the rendered contents... it's possible some JS is messing with the value.